# when use getline(cin, string), cin automatically take its value without ask

Tags: c++, cin, getline

The following code doesn't work well only in first while loop, it automatically give the value to cin, so I don't get the chance to give it a input until the next loop. Why does it happen?

```
char again = 'y';
while (again=='y') { 
  int n=1 , chance = 5, score = 0, level = 1;
  if (n == 1) {
    cout << "Game begin!"<<endl;
  while (chance) {
    cout << "You have " << chance << " chances left." << endl;
    cout<<"level "<<level<<" question!"<<endl;
    vector<string> actorset = game(graph,level);
    int correct = 0;
    string s;
    cout << "\nyour answer is:";
    std::getline(cin, s);
    cout << "Your Answer is " << s <<endl;
    vector<string>::iterator vit = actorset.begin();
    vector<string>::iterator ven = actorset.end();
    cout << "Correct Answers are: "<<endl;
    for ( ; vit != ven; vit++) {
      if (s.compare(*vit) == 0) {
        correct = 1;
      }
      cout << *vit <<'\t'; 
    }
    cout <<'\n';
    if (correct == 0) {
    chance --;
    cout << "Incorrect answer" << endl;
    cout << "Your total score is " << score <<"."<<endl;
    } else {
    score += 10;
    level++;
    cout <<"Correct answer! You get 10 points!"<<endl; 
    cout << "Your total score is " << score <<"."<<endl;
    }
  }
}
cout <<"high score handler"<<endl;
output.open (outfile_name, std::fstream::in | std::fstream::out);
highscore(output,score);
cout << "type y for another try: ";
cin >> again;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The primary culprit is almost certainly you `cin >> again;`.

At least on most systems, you need to press something like <kbd>y</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> to enter the `y` into the program.

That leaves the <kbd>enter</kbd> still waiting in the input buffer. On the next iteration of the loop, `std::getline` looks at the input buffer, sees the <kbd>enter</kbd>, and reads it as an empty line. Since it sees a "line" that's been entered, it doesn't wait for more--it just reads in that empty line, and returns it to your program for processing.

The usual way to avoid this is to avoid mixing character-oriented input and line-oriented input. If you can't avoid it completely, then you usually want to add code to ignore the remainder of an input line between the character-oriented input and the line-oriented input.